# Is it possible to use NgModelController validation on a directive without any input elements?

Tags: angularjs

I built a toggle switch using css where clicking on the control simply adds and removes a CSS class which causes the toggle switch to animate.  I want to get this toggle switch in a form with validation and specifically want to set the control to $dirty = true whenever they click on the control.

I set up my directive by setting `require: 'ngModel'` and then settings the controller in the link function to dirty like this:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl){
            var hasCallback = angular.isDefined(attrs.callback);

            scope.toggle = function(e){

                if(hasCallback){
                    scope.skcallback({event:e});
                }else{
                    scope.ngModel = !scope.ngModel;
                }

                //ctrl.$setDirty(); // This didn't work and didn't even appear to be on the ctrl object
                ctrl.$dirty = true;
                ctrl.$pristine = false;

            }

           scope.$watch('disabled', function(value){
               if(value){
                   elem.addClass('disabled');
               }else{
                   elem.removeClass('disabled');
               }
           })
       }
```

I tried a number of different things to get the validation to work but when I inspect the DOM the control is always set to ng-pristine and doesn't appear to ever get set to dirty.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: so is this just not possible then?

Comment: `$pristine` and `$dirty` has been designed for form and controls I guess. 2 ideas: add a custom permanent class to your element in your `ngClick` callback function or use a `scope` property for that (if your element has its own child or isolate scope).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a custom validator directive (tested with Angular 1.3.8) :

```
mod.directive('cvDirtySet', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      var more = false;

      ctrl.$validators.dummy = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (more) {
          ctrl.$setDirty();
        }
        more = true;
        return true;
      };        

    }
  };
});
```